# Using React Jest Enzyme - How to pass a constructor object to my component with Shallow?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

using react with typescript, jest and enzyme.
trying to unitest a functional component, which has an object
as parameter:

```
const JobListItem: React.FC<{ job: IJob }> = ({ job }) => {
```

in my test - this is how i try to setup the component:

```
const setup = (props={ }) => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<JobListItem<{ job: IJob }> {...props} />)
    return wrapper;
}
```

with simpler components (which don't have the IJob - just props)
the setup works with this syntax:

```
const setup = (props={}) => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<JobList {...props} />)
    return wrapper;
}
```

what am i missing? how can i pass the "IJob" to the shallow?
the error i'm receiving is:

> (property) job: IJob
>   expected 0 type arguments but got 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to provide generics typings to your component wrapper, you can simply do this:

```
describe('Test <JobListItem /> component', () => {
  it('sample test', () => {
     const props = {
        job: .....,
     }
     const JobListItemComponent = <JobListItem {...props} />
     const wrapper = shallow<IJob>(JobListItemComponent);
  });

 });
```

This will provide typechecking, and ensure that the wrapper will only take in props of type `IJob`.

Or, if you just want to make the changes to your code, do not supply the props with a default empty object, because it is not of `IJob` type.

```
const setup = (props: IJob) => {
    const JobListItemComponent = <JobListItem {...props} />
    const wrapper = shallow<IJob>(JobListItemComponent);
    return wrapper;
}
```

Comment: i tried this, it returns a different error: (alias) const JobListItem: React.FC<{
    job: IJob;
}>
import JobListItem
Property 'job' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ job: IJob; }'

Comment: @ShaharLazarovich Ah, I forgot to pass in the props. Please check my edit.

Comment: can you please provide the full setup function code? if i add the above code JobListItem in the first line is marked by vscode and the the error is now:      (alias) const JobListItem: React.FC<{
    job: IJob;
}>
import JobListItem
Property 'job' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ job: IJob; }'

Comment: For reference, This is my code that gives error after suggested changes: const setup = (props = {}) => {
    const JobListItemComponent = <JobListItem {...props} />
    const wrapper = shallow<IJob>(JobListItemComponent);
    return wrapper;
}

Comment: I think the main reason for the errror is because, your `props={}` is empty. Your `props ` could be an empty object. I have made the changes above

Comment: could you please explain the idea behind passing the object - that way i might figure it out because now i get a different error - Property 'job' is missing in type '{ id: string; jobName: string; company: string; }' but required in type '{ job: IJob; }'.

Comment: @ShaharLazarovich yes, sure. It is probably just a matter of type mismatch. You might want to check the interface that is defined for `JobListItem`, and make sure that the props that is passed into the `JobListItem` components match the typings.